# Aldec Riviera-PRO break simulation on SystemVerilog $error or $warning

Tags: system-verilog

Is is possible to configure Aldec Riviera-PRO simulator to break simulation on either `$error` or `$warning` SystemVerilog calls? If it is then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a specific config option for promoting `$error` or `$warning` to a breakpoint in Riviera-PRO, although it worth checking with their support.  You do have a couple of options:

- Replace `$error` with `$fatal`
- Write a VPI module to overload the system tasks with custom C code

The second option would look something like this:

```
#include "vpi_user.h"

// System function overload on $warning and $error to stop sim
static int system_function_overload(char *userdata)
{
    vpiHandle systfref, args_iter, argh;
    struct t_vpi_value argval;
    const char *msg = "*** NO MESSAGE PROVIDED ***";

    // Obtain a handle to the argument list
    systfref = vpi_handle(vpiSysTfCall, NULL);
    args_iter = vpi_iterate(vpiArgument, systfref);

    // Pull out the string passed in as the first argument
    if (args_iter) {
        argh = vpi_scan(args_iter);
        argval.format = vpiStringVal;
        vpi_get_value(argh, &argval);
        vpi_free_object(args_iter);
        msg = argval.value.str;
    }

    vpi_printf("BREAK sim from %s:%d with msg %s\n",
                vpi_get_str(vpiFile, systfref),
                vpi_get(vpiLineNo, systfref),
                msg);
    vpi_control(vpiStop);
    return 0;
}

static void register_system_functions(void)
{
    s_vpi_systf_data tfData = { vpiSysTask, vpiSysTask };

    tfData.sizetf       = NULL;
    tfData.compiletf    = system_function_compiletf;
    tfData.calltf       = system_function_overload;
    tfData.user_data    = NULL;
    tfData.tfname       = "$warning";
    vpi_register_systf( &tfData );
    tfData.tfname       = "$error";
    vpi_register_systf( &tfData );
}

void (*vlog_startup_routines[])(void) = {
    register_system_functions,
    0
};
```

Comment: Custom C is unfortunately not an alternative for my needs as I do not want C compilation or compilers in my tool flow just for this feature. I guess I have to use fatal. To bad, in Modelsim it was possible to achieve this.

Comment: @kraigher Riviera-PRO ships with a compiler, so you can enable VPI with `ccomp -pli -o myvpi.so my_vpi_file.c` and `asim -pli myvpi.so toplevel` in the TCL script that compiles your design.

Comment: I will consider using it but I have to think about the consequences. If the compiler ships with the tool as you say at least this solution does not impose any extra tools to the flow. I am actually in the process of adding SystemVerilog support to the VUnit VHDL test automation framework which I am one of the authors of. One of the design decisions I face is if I should support break on error by default and optional break on warning as we do for VHDL.